# Improving the symmetry of the solution of minimal field equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, conformal-field-theory

> Suppose $u$ is a smooth function on $S^2$ and
> $$
> X_1=x_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}-x_3\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}, X_2=x_3\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}-x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3},X_3=x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}-x_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}
> $$
> be conformal killing vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If $u$ satisfies
> $$
> u(x_1, x_2,x_3)=u(|x_1|, |x_2|,|x_3|)
> $$
> and $X_iu\equiv 0$ for some $i\in\{1,2,3\}$. Can we prove $u$ is axially symmetric, i.e., $u=u(x_i)$.

This problem arise from lemma 8 of the paper [Uniqueness of the mean field equation and rigidity of Hawking Mass](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00526-019-1496-1).

It seems a easy problem but I currently have some difficulty argue this through. Here $u$ is actually the sulotion of the following minimal field equation
$$
-\alpha\Delta_{S^2}u+1=e^{2u},
$$
where $\alpha\in [\frac{1}{2},1)$. I think no additional condition is needed here.

Apprecaite any help!

Comment: So, assume $i=3$. The flow generated by the vector field $X_3$ on $S^2$ has orbits which are circumferences parallel to the plane $x_1,x_2$. Since $X_3u\equiv 0$, this means that $u$ is constant along all these orbits. And this is equivalent to say that $u=u(x_3)$. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Would you explain the orbits a little bit more?